# Changes to make for the function which takes as argument a sequence and returns a list of items without any elements with the same value

Tags: javascript

Implement the function unique_in_order which takes as argument a sequence and returns a list of items without any elements with the same value next to each other and preserving the original order of elements.
For example:

**uniqueInOrder('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') == ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B']**

```js
var uniqueInOrder = function(it) {
  let n = 0;
  let arr = [];
  let i = 0;
  let m = 0;
  length = it.length;
  if (length == 0) {
    return arr
  } else {
    if (n == 0) {
      arr.push(it[0]);
      n += 1;
    }
    while (n < length) {

      if (arr[i] != it[m + 1]) {
        arr.push(it[m + 1])
        i += 1;
        n += 1
      } else {
        m += 1
        n += 1
      }

    }
    return arr
  }
}
console.log(uniqueInOrder('AAAABBBCCDAABBB'));
```

*should reduce duplicates:*

Expected: `'[\'A\', \'B\', \'C\', \'D\', \'A\', \'B\']'`

**instead got**: `'[\'A\', \'B\', \'C\', \'D\', \'A\']'`

*should treat lowercase as different from uppercase:*

Expected: `'[\'A\', \'B\', \'C\', \'c\', \'A\', \'D\']'`

**instead got**: `'[\'A\', \'B\', \'C\', \'c\']'`

Comment: You need to increase `m` at each iteration not just when a match is not found. The same goes for `n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this :

```js
var uniqueInOrder = function(it){
    var arr = it.split('')
    var newArr = []
    arr.forEach((char,idx) => {
        if ( idx !== arr.length && char !== arr[idx+1]) newArr.push(char)
    })
    return newArr
}
```

Comment: can you explain the forEach loop?

Comment: Its an es6 function for arrays , very simillar to a regular for loop. ( you can also use a for loop by the way ) the 'char' is the array element at every index and the idx is just the index.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase `m` at each iteration not just when a match is not found. The same goes for `n`

```js
var uniqueInOrder = function(it) {
  let n = 0;
  let arr = [];
  let i = 0;
  let m = 0;
  length = it.length;
  if (length == 0) {
    return arr
  } else {
    if (n == 0) {
      arr.push(it[0]);
      n += 1;
    }
    while (n < length) {
      if (arr[i] != it[m + 1]) {
        arr.push(it[m + 1])
        i += 1;
        n += 1
      }
      m += 1
      n += 1
    }
    return arr
  }
}
console.log(uniqueInOrder('AAAABBBCCDAABBB'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The Solution can be implemented using

- Using rest & spread operator
- Checking if the input is a string or an array

Below is the working code

```
  var uniqueInOrder=function(iterable){
  if (typeof iterable === 'string') {
            let newArray = [];
            const [...arr] = [...iterable];
            for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if (arr[i] != arr[i + 1]) {
                    newArray.push(arr[i])
                }
            }
             return newArray;
          }
  else{
    let newArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < iterable.length; i++) {
                if (iterable[i] != iterable[i + 1]) {
                    newArray.push(arr[i])
                }
            }
             return newArray;
  }
}
```